# Qual a necessidade de um while em um produtor-consumidor?

Tags: thread, multithreading, sistema-operacional, sincronização

Estou acostumado a programar usando esse while em problemas que envolvem **sincronização de `threds`** pois é assim que as API's geralmente pedem para fazer, mas nunca me questionei o por quê de ser assim. Estou fazendo um curso de sistemas operacionais para rever os conceitos que aprendi na universidade e me deparei com esta dúvida.

[image: exemplo de um cenário produtor-consumidor]

Este breve [vídeo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Kgyo9AuWVuo) (em inglês) fala sobre **exclusão mútua** e o **clássico produtor-consumidor**.
Nele, a professora diz que o consumidor deve esperar em um loop `while (condição)` até que ele seja notificado por um produtor. Por quê não utilizar um simples `if` ao invés de um `while`?

O problema abordado no vídeo é o seguinte:
Os produtores (threads concorrentes) adicionam valores na lista e quando esta lista enche, o consimidor é notificado. O consimidor deve então exibir o conteúdo da lista e depois limpá-la.

No vídeo, ela diz também que a implementação do `wait` deve fazer um `unlock` no `mutex` m e logo depois fazer um `lock` novamente. Não entendi a necessidade desse `unlock/lock` dentro do wait.

Alguém pode me esclarecer estas duas dúvidas? Se possível, exemplificar em C.

Answer (score 1):

Achei a resposta para a pergunta. Basicamente ela foi respondida no próprio curso [neste](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sQn-UOh2qGg) vídeo.

O `while` é necessário porque pode haver mais de um consumer. Quando uma `thread consumer` *T<sub>1</sub>* que está bloqueada em um `wait` é despertada, não há nenhuma garantia de que será esta mesma thread *T<sub>1</sub>* a próxima que conseguirá fazer o lock do mutex. Nesse intervalo de tempo uma outra `thread consumer` *T<sub>2</sub>* poderia ter adquirido o lock e limpado a lista. Se fosse um `if` ao invés de um `while`, caso a thread *T<sub>1</sub>* conseguisse adquirir o lock logo após *T<sub>2</sub>* limpar a lista, *T<sub>1</sub>* iria refazer uma operação que já havia sido feita por *T<sub>2</sub>*. Nesse exemplo em especial não haveriam maiores problemas, pois o consumer apenas printa e limpa a lista, nenhuma operação "crucial" é feita.

> No vídeo, ela diz também que a implementação do wait deve fazer um
>   unlock no mutex m e logo depois fazer um lock novamente. Não entendi a
>   necessidade desse unlock/lock dentro do wait.

A resposta para essa questão é que se o wait não fizesse o unlock, todas as outras threads que tentassem fazer o lock desse mutex não iriam conseguir, pois o wait estaria com o lock, ou seja, haveria um deadlock. Por isso que o wait deve fazer um unlock no mutex. A implementação do wait deve se certificar de colocar na lista de espera a thread que requisitou o lock, liberar o mutex para que outras threads possam fazer locks, esperar até que a variável condicional `list_full` seja sinalizada e então remover a thread da lista e readquirir o lock do mutex para que a seção crítica print_and_remove_all() possa ser executada com segurança.